# Linq problem with group by clause

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have some problems in executing a Linq query with the group by clause in a C# project.
Here following the query:

```
var items = (
     from controlForm in dataContext.ControlForms
       join controlFormStatus 
          in dataContext.ControlFormStatus 
          on controlForm.FK_ControlFormStatus equals controlFormStatus.Id
       join docCheck 
          in dataContext.DocumentChecks 
          on controlForm.Id equals docCheck.FK_ControlForm
       join checkResult 
          in dataContext.CheckResults 
          on docCheck.FK_CheckResult equals checkResult.Id

     where controlForm.FK_ControlCycle.ToString().Equals(controlCycleId)
           & controlFormStatus.Description.Equals(Constants)
           | Description.Equals(Constants.ControlFormStatusApprovalProcessOwner))

     group controlForm by 
           new (controlForm.Id, 
             controlForm.FK_ControlCycle, 
             controlForm.FK_SampleNode, 
             controlForm.FK_Control, 
             controlForm.TestExecutor, 
             controlForm.FK_ControlFormStatus) 

     into ctrlForm

     select 
         new ControlFormReportPartialResults(
           ctrlForm.Key.Id, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_ControlCycle, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_SampleNode, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_Control, 
           ctrlForm.Key.TestExecutor, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_ControlFormStatus , 
           3 / 2)
 );
```

I hope the query will be printed out in the page in a better style than I am seeing at the moment :(.
Anyway I need to get in the constructor of ControlFormReportPartialResults all the fileds I have selected in the group by clause, but it gives me an error type expected.

Any help is really appreciated.

Regards,

Dario

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the rest of the query is correct, your issue is just a syntax problem in your `group by` clause (specifically using the `new` operator to create an anonymous type). You're using parens, but curly braces should be used. This should do the trick:

```
var items = (
     from controlForm in dataContext.ControlForms
       join controlFormStatus 
          in dataContext.ControlFormStatus 
          on controlForm.FK_ControlFormStatus equals controlFormStatus.Id
       join docCheck 
          in dataContext.DocumentChecks 
          on controlForm.Id equals docCheck.FK_ControlForm
       join checkResult 
          in dataContext.CheckResults 
          on docCheck.FK_CheckResult equals checkResult.Id

     where controlForm.FK_ControlCycle.ToString().Equals(controlCycleId)
           & controlFormStatus.Description.Equals(Constants)
           | Description.Equals(Constants.ControlFormStatusApprovalProcessOwner))

     group controlForm by 
           new {controlForm.Id,     /*updated*/ 
             controlForm.FK_ControlCycle, 
             controlForm.FK_SampleNode, 
             controlForm.FK_Control, 
             controlForm.TestExecutor, 
             controlForm.FK_ControlFormStatus} 

     into ctrlForm

     select 
         new ControlFormReportPartialResults(
           ctrlForm.Key.Id, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_ControlCycle, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_SampleNode, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_Control, 
           ctrlForm.Key.TestExecutor, 
           ctrlForm.Key.FK_ControlFormStatus , 
           3 / 2)
 );
```